# How to make a non-static Caffe network architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I would like to implement a neural network architecture in Caffe which will perform differently based on some iterable variable. For example: the full network might use 10 layers for 4 out of 5 training or testing iterations, but for all other iterations it will truncate the network and only use the last 5 layers. This would require that the input to the first layer and the input to the 5th layer have the same dimensionality of course, but my primary question is how to implement this switching between the two architectures during training/testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do that using pycaffe and `caffe.NetSpec()`, but this is not going to be a very nice code...
On the other hand, why don't you train for `i` iterations the full net, save a snapshot, and then "warm start" the reduced model with the snapshot you saved?
That is: have `'full_trainval.prototxt'` with `'full_solver.prototxt'` configured to train the full net for `i` iterations, and `'top_trainval.prototxt'` with `'top_solver.prototxt'` configured to train only the top layers of the net. Then

```
~$ $CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/caffe train -solver full_solver.prototxt
```

When this stage is through, make sure you have the final sanpshot saved, and then

```
~$ $CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/caffe train -solver top_solver.prototxt -snapshot full_train_last_snapshot.solverstate
```

Finally, you could use [`net_surgery`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) to merge the weights of the two phases into a single full net.